# How to remove wrapped line from Combobox option. - RapidClipseX/Vaadin 14

Tags: vaadin14, rapidclipse

I am Using RapidclipseX and Vaadin 14, I want to know how to make this Combobox option not wrapped?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An obvious answer is to set the width of the ComboBox to be wider, e.g. comboBox.setWidth("200px").

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp
Teaches us that there is no other option really then be wide enough to accommodate the entire string.

Assuming that you want a drop-down that's wider than the box: you are using Vaadin 14, so it's important it's not in legacy (10-13) mode so that the new style of CSS is being used.
`@CssImport(value = "./styles/vaadin-combo-box.css", themeFor = "vaadin-combo-box")`
would allow you to style the ComboBox.

But, if you look [here]
(https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-combo-box/blob/master/src/vaadin-combo-box.html) you'll see that the vaadin-combo-box-dropdown-wrapper is not a 'part' so it cannot be styled on its own, and expanding the vaadin-text-field will effectively make the whole ComboBox larger.

So you will have to be wide enough with that box or file a feature request on GitHub.

Comment: Thank You, Enver but I do not know how to use this feature. Can you give an example. How I can do it. The feature Rapidclipse gave is HTMLimport and that is what I know. I put that line above my class but do not know how to customize it. Nor I can find the answer in Book Of Vaadin 14.

Comment: What I was trying to say is: after some investigation I am convinced that at this time the ComboBox simply has to be wide enough. I am sure RapidClipseX will support this one way or another, probably graphically.
If you feel this is a bug or if you request as a feature that the width of the overlay that pops out underneath the original button should be adjustable separately, please file this in github: https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-combo-box/issues

Comment: https://vaadin.com/learn/training/v14-theming shows how a TextField inside a ComboBox can be styled at 30:44 - so I have to correct my thinking that this cannot be done in Vaadin 14. I am afraid I don't know how to apply this to RapidClipseX though.

Comment: I have raised an issue in the link that you have provided in the comment. https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-combo-box/issues/892